# Is there a better way to make objects move automatically

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am making objects (in this case a car) automatically move according to a point in time like this:

```
    public Image car1_right;
    public int k;
    public float i;
    public float j;

    void Start()
    {
        k = 1;
        i = 0f;
        j = 0f;
        car1_right.enabled = false;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (TimeManager.gametimeDecimal == 9.0m && k == 1)
        {
            car1_right.enabled = true;
            InvokeRepeating("car_move_1", 0f, 0.05f);
            k = 2;
        }
        if (TimeManager.gametimeDecimal == 23.0m && k == 2)
        {
            k = 1;
            i = 0f;
            j = 0f;
        }
    }
    void car_move_1()
    {
        car1_right.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-35.0f + i, 531f - j, 0);
        i += 1.8f;
        j += 0.85f;
    }
```

The problem is, to add more 2 cars, I have to create 3 more variables for each (which would be six) and triplicate the code.

Do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: What are the variables you would have to add?  Am I correct in guessing `k`, `i`, and `j`?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Can you expand your code some, to include the declaration of the variables?  It looks like they are declared at the class level.

Comment: Is the method car_move_1 used to move car1?

Comment: Can you please give meaningful names to the variables i, j, and k? i and j seem to be used as coordinates. And k seems to be used as a switch, as the only possible values you've shown are 1 and 2.

Comment: Each car should be modeled with its own class, say `Car`, which would be responsible for tracking its own location (with the three variables) and for moving.  *This* class would then use a list of cars.  It looks like you're trying to add car data directly to this class and you've discovered how unscalable that is.

Comment: Yes, the method car_move_1 is used to move car1

Comment: `i` and `j` are reasonable names for coordinate variables, but it looks like `k` isn't part of a coordinate, so it should have a proper name for clarity.  What does `k` signify?  I would like to add, this isn't meant as a criticism of your code.  We just want to ensure we fully understand your code before we start recommending changes.

Comment: @Amy, yes it is just a switch, I guess I need to go deeper in classes to understand how to make it work but what you said makes total sense.

Comment: @GrowAnimation if I add an answer to your question that contains pseudocode instead of actual code, so you can implement it yourself, would that be acceptable?  I think once the idea is presented you'll be able to run with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public struct Position
{            
    public double X { get; set; } 
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
public class Car
{
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public Position Position { get; private set; }
    public bool IsInMotion { get; set; }
    public void MoveCar(Position position)
    {
        if (IsEnabled && !IsInMotion)
        {
            Position = position;
        }
    }
}

class CarSimulator
{
    List<Car> cars = new List<Car>(); // populate it
    void MoveAllCars()
    {
        foreach (var car in cars)
        {
            car.MoveCar(GetPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

It might look something like this. You'll decide what logic you need to implement.

Comment: I am confused, I don't want all cars to move at the same time but according to time conditions. Also, they need to keep moving, not just 1 step, I need to use Update().

Comment: Ok, I've changed the position to avoid confusing you. The GetPosition() method must return position - you'll decide what that position is. When do cars move? Do all cars ever stop moving?